# Count Number of Sheets Until Specific One

Tags: excel, vba, count, conditional-statements, worksheet

Is there a way within vba to count the number of worksheets present in a workbook until a certain worksheet name is reached. For example, the worksheet that I am trying to stop at is called "Summary". I want to know how many sheets are present before that sheet including the "Summary" one.

Comment: [`Worksheets("Summary").Index`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.index)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to stack overflow/coding and did not see the undercomplicated response until I finished my way over-complicated version.

Sub CountingSheets()

```
test1 = Sheets.Count
Count = 0
For I = 1 To test1
    If Sheets(I).Name <> Sheets("Summary").Name Then
        Count = Count + 1
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
```

End Sub